# Email is not being sent to specific email providers from godaddy

Tags: php, email

After 1.5 hours on the phone and at least an hour of online chatting with the customer service people at godaddy, I didn't move anywhere.

a simple **mail() function in php isn't sending emails to @hotmail.com, @mail.com**, and my university email. I am sure there is more though.

**@yahoo.com and @gmail.com work no problem regardless if I change the header or not.**

On the phone they told me it's the email service blocking it due to spoofing, sure but than I used a **simple mail(example@hotmail.com, SUBJECT, BODY) and it still didn't go through.**

In the chat support, we **updated the SPF (TXT)** lines under DNS Zone to be directed to my server or something like that and it was supposed to fix it after 24 hours, but still nothing.

He also checked the error logs and said everything looked like it went through and there were **no bounces** at all.

Obviously contacting each email service and telling them to unblock my godaddy server is slightly weird in my logic. I have a bad feeling that it's godaddy that is messing up

Please help! My whole project is based on emails being sent to for registration conformation, password recoveries, news and more..

EDIT:

```
The TXT records found for your domain are:
v=spf1 a mx ptr a:dedrelay.secureserver.net include:secureserver.net ~all

Checking to see if there is a valid SPF record.

Found v=spf1 record for somesite.com:
v=spf1 a mx ptr a:dedrelay.secureserver.net include:secureserver.net ~all

evaluating...
Results - PermError SPF Permanent Error: Too many DNS lookups
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not have to be GoDaddy's fault

Hotmail and others can be VERY strict about emails (they just delete it if it's a tiny bit suspicious/bot/spam-looking). Sometimes especially when using php mail()

And **php's mail() function really can't be used for anything half-serious**. + it's a horrorshow messing with those headers

You should consider using a SMTP mailer like [PHPmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or alternatives. Let their well-developed script handle all the header stuff etc. Much higher chance of mails getting through

Or you could use an external mailer API (SendGrid, PostMark, many others)

Comment: Also, check your SPF record. Maybe post the result here. Google "check SPF". http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html is one

Comment: I updated my question with the results above. PHPmailer looks promising im in the middle of figuring out how to install it hopefully it works. In the meantime, looks like there is some error with the SPF :/

Comment: I'm no SPF genius, but to me your setting looks quite ok for this (I have about the same setup and it works)

Comment: for phpmailer, $mail->Host = 'localhost'; right? i tried sending an email and i got "Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed."

Comment: Are you testing on a local machine (your computer)? It could take some time to adjust SMTP for both local machine and then live site (different smtp settings, host may have specific requirements)

Comment: no i uploaded to my godaddy server. then went to the url where i had the main php file and saw the message. should i try putting smtp.godaddy.com or something else? I also read somewhere about the port being used at godaddy (port:25) is spammy so it's good to change it or something like that

Comment: Check GoDaddy's default smtp/port, it can be anything. Else, try that. Start with port 25, and test. And set $mail->SMTPAuth = false; Don't need that for starters (maybe). Start getting through to the SMTP/port

Comment: post 25, and 465 didn't work. i set relay-hosting.secureserver.net too

Comment: Find out what smtp address and port you need. Unless GoDaddy does not support that..

Comment: Another thing: The sender email address has to be one you have at GoDaddy

Comment: got it to work! auth must be on, port 465, smptout not relay-hosting! that combo did it for me!

Comment: Great :) I have made a separate file for all the phpmailer settings (require). Makes it much easier to just setup a mail